# Meaning of move on

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What is meaning of this statement:

> It is ok. We will need to move on.

The context is that I wanted to apologize for a problem or conflict. When I told the person I wanted to apologize, they said "It's ok. We will need to move on."

Comment: If you *ask* for "meaning in context" we will *need* context...

Comment: *In general,* it means don't bother or worry too much for what has happened. Keep going, don't disturb your routine and stick to your goals.

Comment: I ask someone pls call me(bcoz she is not picking up call) I want to apologize and have smooth relationship then she tell me this.

Comment: It's difficult to read *her* mind. It's purely opinion based. And, here, it's **her opinion**!

Comment: what's yr thought by this word, its after too much fight on one issue

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is English Language Learners not Relationship Advice - from the comments it is still ambiguous what the dialogue partner said and OP will have to ask for clarification there.

Comment: NO there is not

Comment: I'll use ~ to mean "roughly means / could be understood as". *It is ok* ~ "Don't worry"; *We will need to move on* is a bit trickier because **[move on](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/move-on)** could mean several things. Her tone should've given you a clue whether she meant "We will need to move on, each on our own way" or "We will need to move on together".

Comment: I have edited the question to include the context specified by the OP in the comment. I believe it is answerable now, and a valid question. The OP supplies enough information to suggest that the utterance was made after a conflict occurred. To move on, in this context, quite certainly means the following, or something very closely related to it: (intransitive) to put a difficult experience behind one and progress mentally or emotionally http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/move-on

Comment: I do not see a request for "relationship advice." It is a request for help with the meaning of some language. Obviously, I think, in particular with the phrasal verb "move on." Since this is a multi-word item, and since it has specialized meaning, I think it's a valid question (not necessarily easy to research for an ELL). Moreover, I do not understand why we wouldn't "know what the dialogue partner said" when the OP has quoted that person. The question should be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Move on* can be a phrasal verb that means "to consider finished/completed" or "to stop worrying about/thinking about/remembering something."

It's commonly used with failed relationships or traumatic events, but can be used with any type of event or task.  It can imply that you encountered something that blocked your progress and decided it was more worth it to stop rather than waste time continuing.

> Are you still cleaning the kitchen?
>
> No, the faucet in the sink is broken.  I've moved on and am now cleaning the living room.

*From* is the preposition to use if you want to include the event or task.

> No. I've moved on from cleaning the kitchen and am now cleaning the living room.

---

Note that *move on* can also still mean to physically move on to something, in which case *move* will have an object.

> I moved the car on the driveway.

Also: *make a move on X* means "to do something to X that escalates the situation or causes progress" - and *get a move on* is equivalent to saying "hurry up" or "go/do something faster."